# Какой встроенный метод php можно использовать для изменений элементов массива?

Tags: php

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
    if ($numbers[$i] < 0) {
      $numbers[$i] = 0;
    }

    if ($numbers[$i] > 0) {
      $numbers[$i] *= 2;
    }
  }
```

Я хочу найти функцию в php, которая будет делать то же самое, но нативно (чтобы можно было указать условия). Есть ли такое? Нужно для лабораторной, чтобы сравнить время выполнение встроенных функций и собственных.

Comment: ну array_walk например

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь что тут будет хоть какая-то разница между этими подходами.

Comment: А filter_input() можно как-то здесь применить? Или какие-нибудь другие функции фильтрации

Comment: Можно, но сначала надо понять - зачем

Comment: array_map  можно